# How to connect multiple DB in one Moodle 3.8 instance?

Tags: mysql, moodle

We are developing LMS application using moodle 3.8. I have two DB one for Moodle Database, I want to connect another mysql DB which is having my company employee details. How to connect multiple databases in moodle config.php file.

Please help.

Regards
Girija S

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is setup a slave and master db instances in config file. If say your slave is readonly:

1. When moodle is setup and working, append the read-replica options to config.php in the dboptions sections:

   'readonly' => [
   'instance' => '192.168.1.2',
   'connecttimeout' => 2,
   'latency' => 0.5,
   'exclude_tables' => [
   'config',
   ],
   ]
2. Log into moodle

   Confirm that you see SELECT queries appearing in the logs on both the slave and master

   Confirm that you do not see any DELETE, TRUNCATE, INSERT, or UPDATE queries occuring on the slave

   Confirm that you see a range of DELETE, TRUNCATE, INSERT, or UPDATE queries occuring on the master

Comment: No. I don't want master slave concept of same DB. I want to connect 2 different mysql DB in single moodle instance. As I mentioned on is moodle DB another one is Employee DB